# Multiple Laravel Horizon workers per supervisor using supervisord

Tags: laravel, redis, supervisord, laravel-horizon

I'm just moving our Laravel v8 queue driver from db to redis, using Horizon for management.

No matter what I configured in `config/horizon.php`, I was only getting either one worker process across all my queues or one worker per queue - but with no auto-balancing.

I modified the supervisor `scheduler.conf` to run 2 (or more) processes:

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /www/E3/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=web
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

but this seems to spawn multiple supervisors (in Horizon parlance) with one worker each, rather than multiple workers per supervisor:

[image: Horizon showing multiple supervisors]

I think Horizon is configured correctly:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['high', 'updatestock', 'priceapi', 'pubsub', 'klaviyo', 'default', 'low'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'processes' => 2,
            'minProcesses' => 2,
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'maxTime' => 3600, // how long the process can run before restarting (to avoid memory leaks)
            'maxJobs' => 0,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 3,
            'timeout' => 60,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],

    'environments' => [

        'staging' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'maxProcesses' => 3,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Also, at some point while attempting various changes I'm no longer getting any data shown in pending/completed - the json responses show counts, but not the job data, for instance in `/horizon/api/jobs/completed?starting_at=-1&limit=50`:

```json
{
    "jobs": [],
    "total": 13157
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you dont need to worry about supervisor.conf .
Since based on the horizon.php - laravel will auto-scale amount of "workers".

Try to change  maxProcesses and test it out.